# Android AsyncTask getting NetworkOnMainThreadException when called a second time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, parse-platform, networkonmainthread

I'm getting some data off Parse.com in my app
When it first starts up, it checks the cache if available and displays it, then the user can pull-to-refresh to get the latest data
When the first refresh action is called, everything works great, but when I try to refresh a second time I get the NetworkOnMainThreadException force close

This is the calling method (I'm using Android support's swipe-to-refresh view)

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    // this part is merely a check, crashes both with or without this
    if(!runningTask.getClass().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))
        runningTask.cancel(true);

    runningTask = new DownloadEvents(true).execute();
}
```

This is the async task

```
private class DownloadEvents extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,  ArrayList<Event>> {
    boolean forceDownload;

    String errorString = "";
    public DownloadEvents(boolean forceDownload) {
        this.forceDownload = forceDownload;
        Parse.initialize(getActivity(), #API KEY CENSORED#);
    }

    // Do the long-running work in here
    protected ArrayList<Event> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        List<ParseObject> events = null;
        PreferencesHelper ph = new PreferencesHelper(getActivity());

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> eventsQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("events");
        try {
            eventsQuery.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.CACHE_ONLY);
            events = eventsQuery.find();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(forceDownload || System.currentTimeMillis() - ph.getLastEventsDownloadTime() > 43200000 || events == null)
        {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            try {
                eventsQuery.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE);
                events = eventsQuery.find();
                ph.setLastEventsDownloadTime();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }

        // creating classes and sorting goes here

        return eventsList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        super.onPreExecute(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Event> events) {
        if(events.size() > 0)
        {
            EventsAdapter adapter = new EventsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.events_card, events);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        if(errorString != "")
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

Even if I force the download as the app start, it's always the second pulldown that crashes it, not the second time it downloads something

Please don't suggest turning off the NetworkOnMainThread strict rule, that's not a solution

Edit: here's the logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mdk.test, PID: 24048
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.shutdownAndFreeSslNative(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1102)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.close(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1097)
at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.close(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:205)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.close(DefaultClientConnection.java:161)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.closeConnection(AbstractConnPool.java:320)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.shutdown(ConnPoolByRoute.java:678)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.shutdown(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:256)
at com.parse.ParseRequest.initialize(ParseRequest.java:118)
at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:109)
at com.mdk.test.EventsFragment$DownloadEvents.<init>(EventsFragment.java:136)
at com.mdk.test.EventsFragment.onRefresh(EventsFragment.java:223)
at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.startRefresh(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:441)
at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onTouchEvent(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:399)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8073)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2253)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1987)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2198)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1649)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2717)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2159)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8263)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4013)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3892)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3454)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3507)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3473)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3583)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3481)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3454)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3507)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3473)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3481)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3454)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5656)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5627)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5761)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at android.view.InputEv
```

Comment: `Please don't suggest turning off the NetworkOnMainThread strict rule,` what do you mean by that? Do you have any of that now?

Comment: `if(errorString != "")` That is invalid code. Change to `if(!errorString.equals(""))`.

Comment: Post thestacktrace/logcat please.

Comment: `return eventsList;`? What is that? Why not `return events`?

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` usually means exactly that: network on main thread (which this code wouldn't seem to be able to cause). Please post the logcat stack trace.

Comment: I'll provide the logcat later today, don't know why I forgot to post it in the first place. The reason I'm returning eventsList is because I'm looping through the ParseObject files to create individual "Event" classes for a better management (sorting, date formatting, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Parse.initialize()` is in the async task constructor that gets executed in the main thread and it invokes a network operation.

Move the call to `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Yeah, I was **just** playing with it now, tried to move it into the doInBackground() and of course it now works fine, I was coming back to this page to post the results... why doesn't it crash the app on the first call though?

Comment: Guess: Likely the first call was already on a background thread, or less likely, the initialization doesn't always invoke a network operation.

Comment: My bet is on your second guess, the first initialization may not require a connection but if you try to "reset" it by re-initializing it, it tries to go online and get a new token of sorts

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly where the problem occurs, because you didn't post the stacktrace, but this line looks suspicious:

```
swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

You can't modify any views on your doInBackground, and it looks like this might be doing just that.

Another fishy line is:

```
PreferencesHelper ph = new PreferencesHelper(getActivity());
```

Apparantly this object needs the activity, which may or may not cause a NetworkOnMainThread exception later on. You can't touch the UI in your doInBackGround method.

Just keep the doInBackground clean and only do the network stuff there, don't entangle it with other things.

Comment: Those are both good points, but they don't trigger any error (not that I noticed) and they work just fine on the first refresh, which again makes no sense to me, it's like only the second pull causes the crash

Answer (score 0):

```
event.size()
```

For null data will throw an exception error, however not sure if that is the exact issue you are facing.